# How to set Minimum/Maximum Window Size for MonoGame?

Tags: c#, resize, window, monogame

So I've made my Game class, set `Window.AllowUserResizing = true;` and now I have a resizable window. However, while I can set the initial resolution through `GraphicsDeviceManager.PreferredBackBufferWidth / PreferredBackBufferHeight`, I cannot find any intuitive way to set the minimum/maximum window size the user is allowed to resize to.

Assuming it's possible, how would I go about doing this? (Preferably in a way that multi-platform compatible)

Answer (score 1):

You can listen `GameWindow.ClientSizeChanged` event and restrict the back buffer's size.